# How can I play this m3u8 with ExoPlayer?

Tags: android, video-streaming, exoplayer, m3u8

I have this `m3u8` file:
https://iptv-org.github.io/iptv/languages/tur.m3u

This file not standard `m3u8` if you open it with `NotePad++` or `SublimeText` you will see. There is list of differences `m3u8` and playing next to next. But I don't know how can I implement this `m3u8` in `ExoPlayer`.

Anyone have idea?
Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not related to android-studio. anyway idk about android but vlc player in windows is able to play with m3u8, check if there's a version of vlc for android.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `m3u8` is `playlist` and I parsed it with `PHP`. There is no way to play in `exoplayer`. We should parse it first.

Answer (score 1):

You can play m3u playlist with exoplayer, there is api for that.To play m3u playlist you must create media source with HlsMediaSource.Factory api, like this

```
private fun buildMediaSource(uri: Uri): MediaSource {
    val dataSourceFactory: DataSource.Factory = DefaultDataSource.Factory(context)
    return HlsMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(uri))
}
```

you just need to download your m3u file your self(at least I have not found a way yet, to make exoplayer do that stuff for us), or may be you already have that file - so you can use path to that file as parameter of the function above